# ubuntu 13.10 video good but sound choppy on NHL Gamecenter Live at 1600 Kbps

Tags: sound

I have an :

> AMD dual core 2.4 GHz x64 4600+
>  2 GB dual-channel RAM, 
>   7200-rpm HDD 
>  ASUS Nforce 210 1GB 64-bit graphics card 
>   using a DVI connection 
>  Gateway 24" `1920x1080` HD display.

My internet is 3 Mbits. When I set a live game on NHL Gamecenter Live to 1600 Kbps, the video is just fine unless the camera is panning right from one end of the ice to the other in less than one second.

In which case the video does stutter very slightly. But the announcers' voices are slightly choppy, while the crowd noise and sounds of play on the ice are significantly choppy.

Can someone help me figure out what the problem is and how I can maybe solve it?

Comment: Awesome, looking forward to getting this service, and happy to see it works on Ubuntu!

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a solution. I just went and scanned for updates on my entire system. Updated it all, restarted and I went Gamecenter to playback a game and the audio skipping had stopped. Give updating everything a try. Hope it helps!